# Do que se trata a Lei de Demétrio?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Numa prova de concurso, encontrei a seguinte pergunta:

> Em Programação Orientada a Objetos, a lei de Demétrio (*Law of Demeter*)
>   diz que um método m de um objeto O não deve invocar métodos dos
>   seguintes tipos de objetos: (A) do próprio O. (B) parâmetros de m. (C)
>   qualquer objeto criado/instanciado em m. (D) objetos retornados pela
>   chamada de outros métodos. (E) atributos de O. ([Conhecimentos Específicos -
>    Analista de Sistema - q54 - 2013](https://arquivo.pciconcursos.com.br/provas/19661905/d12ed74f7858/al_mt_2013_analista_de_sistemas_programador_prova_tipo_01.pdf) )

Dentre essas, a resposta certa seria "*(C) qualquer objeto criado/instanciado em m*" de acordo com o gabarito.

Do que se trata essa tal Lei de Demétrio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem um erro de tradução aí.

[Da Wikipedia sobre a tal lei:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

> It is so named for its origin in the Demeter Project, an adaptive programming and aspect-oriented programming effort. The project was named in honor of Demeter, “distribution-mother” and the Greek god**dess** of agriculture.

É o nome da Deusa Deméter, ou Demetra.

Fora isso, a tal lei diz que uma unidade de código deve conhecer e se comunicar somente com as unidades mais próximas de si e que lhe são diretamente relacionadas. De novo do wiki:

> When applied to object-oriented programs(...) an object A can request a service (call a method) of an object instance B, but object A should not "reach through" object B to access yet another object

*"Quando aplicado a OO (...) um objeto A pode requisitar um serviço (chamar um método) de uma instância de objeto B, mas o objeto A não pode "atravessar" o objeto B para acessar um terceiro objeto".*

No seu caso, o método "m" pode acessar de boas o pai dele (o tipo "O"), seus irmãos (outros membros de "O"), seus próprios parâmetros etc. A lei é violada se "m" acessar outros objetos que foram criados por outros métodos, ou seja, alternativa **D**.

Answer (score 2):

Lei de Demetrio ou O Princípio do Mínimo Conhecimento nos orienta a reduzir as interações entre os objetos, aconselhando-nos ao encapsulamento de funções, rotinas, lógicas internas e sistemas. Um sistema com muitas dependências entre múltiplas classes é um sistema frágil, de difícil manutenção e complexo demais para ser compreendido por todos.

“Isso significa que, ao projetarmos um sistema, devemos tomar cuidado com o número de classes com que qualquer objeto interage e também com a forma como essa interação ocorre (…) Este princípio nos impede de criar projetos com um grande número de classes interconectadas, o que faz com que qualquer alteração numa parte do sistema exerça um efeito em cascata sobre outras partes.” (Freeman, 2005, p. 221)
O princípio nos fornece algumas dicas: pegamos um objeto qualquer e, a partir de qualquer método para esse objeto, só podemos invocar métodos que pertençam ao próprio objeto, a objetos que tenham sido passados como parâmetros para o método, a qualquer objeto que seja criado ou instanciado pelo método e, finalmente, a quaisquer componentes do objeto.

fonte: https://ferhenriquef.com/2010/07/18/principios-de-projetos-orientados-a-objetos/

Comment: "só podemos invocar métodos ... (de) qualquer objeto que seja criado ou instanciado pelo método", mas a resposta C dada na pergunta diz exatamente o contrário: "um método m de um objeto O **não deve** invocar métodos ... (de) qualquer objeto criado/instanciado em m". Então a resposta está errada?