# Listagem de ArrayList<Obj> java

Tags: java

Qual a vantagem de usar em uma listagem:

```
    for(Obj o : lista){
       // operacao
    }
```

ao invés de:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
       // operação
    }
```

Comment: Quantas você quer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou falar aqui das vantagens de cada uma das estratégias individualmente. Existem situações em que uma é melhor do que a outra e vice-versa.

Mas, antes, falar um pouco sobre o `foreach`.

Em [java](/questions/tagged/java), o `foreach` é uma proposta de iteração "melhorada" para Java 5 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518471/4438007) [2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Em vetores tradicionais (não `Collection`, mas `int[]` ou `Obj[]`), o `foreach` é a mesma coisa que uma iteração pelo índice. A seguir, dois exemplos de iterações equivalentes:

```
Obj[] array = //... atributi o valor

// jeito "melhorado"
for (Obj o: array) {
    // faz algo...
}

// jeito "tradicional" que foi escondido pelo "foreach"
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    Obj o = array[i];
    // faz algo
}
```

No caso para elementos do mundo `Collections`, a situação é um pouco mais complexa. Esses elementos (como `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, `LinkedList`, `TreeSet` ...) são elementos *iteráveis*. E o Java tem uma marcação especial para esses elementos: eles implementam a interface [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Neste caso em específico, a iteração "tradicional" não podia seguir um índice. Em muitas vezes, porque não havia índice para se seguir [java8-hashset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)). Em outros, porque seguir um índice era uma alternativa ineficiente ([`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)). Para esses casos, desde o Java 2, era necessário fazer uma iteração através de iteradores *old-school*. E o `foreach` para as coleções (na verdade, para tudo que implementa `Iterable`) é um açúcar sintático que, depois de compilado, acaba possuindo um iterador *old-school* por baixo. Veja exemplo extraído [dessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518471/4438007):

```
List<String> someList = // ... povoa a lista com os valores adequados ...

// método melhorado
for (String item : someList) {
    System.out.println(item);
}

// método old-school
for (Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Então, o `foreach` neste contexto serve para reduzir a complexidade do código escrita pelo programador.

## Vantagens do `foreach`

1. Método de acesso adequado para a estrutura adequada
   No caso de um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), acessar um elemento na posição `i` é instantâneo. Tão instantâneo quanto fazer, para um vetor `Obj[] array`, `array[i]`.
   No caso de um [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), entretanto, a conversa é outra. Acessar a posição arbitrária `i` exige sair da raiz da lista e contar `i` nós (raiz inclusa). Isso significa que são necessários `i` saltos em memória. Então, o seguinte código tem tempo linear para `ArrayList`, porém quadrático para `LinkedList`:

   ```
   List<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(l.get(i));
   }
   ```

   No caso da `LinkedList`, o `Iterator` dela pode ser feito de maneira inteligente, na qual se armazena qual o nó atual da lista para, ao chamar `next`, ir para o nó seguinte. Como cada iterador é chamado uma única vez, tem seu elemento de valor extraído imediatamente e só então se faz o salto para o nó seguinte, o `foreach` garante que o seguinte código seja executado em tempo linear para qualquer lista:

   ```
   List<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   for (String e: l) {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
   ```
2. Concisão de código e clareza da mensagem passada
   Quando se usa o `foreach`, a pessoa que lê seu código e que está acostumada com Java vai, instantaneamente, reconhecer que você precisa passar por todos os elementos (ou até um em específico, no caso de haver desvio de fluxo, como `break`, ou `return`, ou lançamento de exceção). Ele também saberá de imediato qual a variável que carregará o valor sendo iterado. Sem pestanejar, ele simplesmente vai bater o olho e perceber tudo isso.
   Quando se faz uma iteração a partir do índice, você precisa fazer o código de resgate, e as vezes isso pode acabar ficando um pouco confuso se você não fizer com cuidado:

   ```
   List<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
       String e = l.get(i);
       System.out.println(e);
   }
   ```

   Aqui, num código feito sem muito cuidado, o leitor precisa olhar com um pouco mais de critério para saber qual é o valor de `e` em cada instante.
3. Garantia contra erros de digitação
   Eu mesmo sem querer cometi um erro de digitação a primeira vez que estava escrevendo os exemplos aqui:

   ```
   List<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); l++) {
       System.out.println(l.get(i));
   }
   ```

   Sim, eu mandei "incrementar" em `l`, sendo que `l` é uma lista e portanto eu obteria um erro de compilação neste código.
4. Garantia contra erros de lógica
   Imagina que você, como rapaz esperto, tenta otimizar a escrita do `for` de maneira mais inteligente. Você vai ao mesmo tempo aumentar o índice e pegar o novo valor para a variável `e`:

   ```
   List<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   for (int i = 0, String e = l.get(0); i < l.size(); i++, e = l.get(i)) {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
   ```

   Identificou o erro de lógica? Não? Pois bem, aqui a gente teria obtida uma exceção: [`IndexOutOfBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Isso porque, após a execução do último laço, estou fazendo `e = l.get(i)`, sendo que, neste momento, `i == l.size()`. Como `l` é indexado começando por zero, isso significa que p último elemento está, necessariamente, no índice `l.size() - 1`.
5. Contrato de coleção imutável
   Esse detalhe aqui é um tanto quanto mais sutil...
   Quando se está usando um `Iterator`, alterar a coleção a qual ele se refere sem ser através dos comandos especiais do `Iterator`, ocasiona em um [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Isso significa que, se você não avisar ao iterador, você **não pode** alterar a estrutura do iterável. Por mudança de estrutura, pode acontecer adição/remoção de elementos estruturais da lista ou, até mesmo, setar um novo valor a um elemento estrutural pré-existente.
   Como no `foreach` você não tem o mínimo acesso ao `Iterator` que está por de baixo dos panos, você não pode alterar a coleção. Isso significa que a lista sempre será a mesma de quando você começou.

## Vantagens do`for` via índice

1. Parear índice com elemento
   Se você quiser parear usando `foreach`, você precisa manter uma variável por fora, atualizando-a toda hora que um novo laço se inicia. Quando você faz o resgate direto conhecendo o índice, a relação entre o índice `i` e o elemento `e` simplesmente existe.
2. Capacidade de alterar valor na lista
   Bem, se você deseja alterar o valor (inserir um novo objeto) na posição `i` da lista, baseado no objeto anterior dessa mesma posição `i`, então só lhe resta usar essa forma de laço. Ou então usar o `Iterator` bem *old-school*. E boa sorte tentando explicar aos colegas de projeto o que foi aquilo.
3. Performance para casos específicos
   Podem existir casos em que fazer o acesso através do índice seja mais vantajoso em termos de performance computacional. Eu particularmente conheço apenas um caso em que isso é passível de ocorrer: quando a classe `Iterable` fornece acesso para o seu vetor interior. Nesse caso, pegar o vetor e acessar  posição `i` evita uma chamada de método:

   ```
   MyListExposable<String> l = // ... povoa a lista ...
   String[] v = l.classicArray;
   for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
       String e = v[i];
       System.out.println(e);
   }
   ```

   Note que, mesmo assim, é possível que o ganho seja marginal ou mesmo desprezível.
4. Ordem de busca específica
   Talvez você precisa iterar os elementos do último ao primeiro? Nesse caso, talvez o seu iterável não lhe forneça um iterador pronto para isso. Mas se for algo indexável, você pode definir facilmente qual o índice que vai começar, como vai evoluir o índice dado o estado atual do índice e muito mais.
   Mesmo assim, é questionável qualquer ganho com isso.

## Conclusão

No caso geral, justamente pela [lei de Deméter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216996/64969), o uso da `foreach` obtém uma performance `o(n)` na maioria dos casos (classes bem implementadas). Porém, caso haja a garantia de se saber exatamente qual a implementação que será passada, **talvez** seja possível obter uma performance melhor pela busca indexada (a [complexidade assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237026/64969) continua a mesma na melhor das opções).

Usar o `foreach` também faz com que se tenha menos o que se escrever. Menos escrita, menos bugs. Quanto mais você precise que o programador gere, maior a probabilidade dele passar um erro de digitação ou então um sutil erro de lógica. Esconder a complexidade por traz de um código deixa-o mais "declarativo" e menos "imperativo" [5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/64969). Por questões de manutenção e leitura de código, muitas vezes é melhor focar no "QUÊ" do que no "COMO", e uma escrita mais imperativa invariavelmente foca mais no "COMO" [6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81879/64969).

Usar o `foreach` também é uma estratégia para fazer uma "computação de lista fixa". Isso significa que os elementos passados na lista vão ser verificados e eles não podem ser trocados durante diretamente durante o laço. Vale ressaltar que seguir o princípio de [`fail-fast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377532/4438007) garante que toda alteração na lista gerará um erro na próxima iteração, tentando assim manter a integridade do que se está trabalhando.

Usar um `for` indexado já irá lhe fornecer, imediatamente, o elemento e seu índice associado. Diferentemente do `foreach`, onde para manter o índice associado seria necessário um controle externo. E no `foreach` também não é garantido que o `i`-ésimo elemento realmente pertença ao índice `i`, já que a ordem do iterador é arbitrária.

---

Links usados:

- [Falha rápida, SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377532/4438007)
- [`foreach`, SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518471/4438007)
- [`foreach` no Java 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
- [Java 8, `Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)
- [Java 8, `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)
- [Java 8, `LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
- [Java 8, `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [Java 8, `IndexOutOfBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)
- [Java 8, `ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)
- [Sobre a lei de Deméter, SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216996/64969)
- [Sobre complexidade assintótica, SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237026/64969)
- [Pergunta sobre declarativo vs imperativo, SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/64969)
- [Resposta sobre declarativo vs imperativo, SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81879/64969), focando no **O QUÊ** e no **COMO**